# Null reference issue when adding services running on a terminal server to a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, service, dictionary

In VB.NET, I am trying to retrieve what services are running on a TS using the following code:

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess
...
Dim dictservice As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Services)

Public Sub GetService()
    Dim localServices As ServiceController() = ServiceController.GetServices()
    For Each service As ServiceController In localServices
        dictservice.Add(service.DisplayName, New Services(service.DisplayName, service.ServiceName, service.Status.ToString))
    Next
End Sub
```

My services class is as follows:

```
Class Services
    Private _displayName As String
    Private _serviceName As String
    Private _serviceStatus As String

    Sub New(ByVal DisplayName As String, ByVal ServiceName As Object, ByVal ServiceStatus As String)
        _displayName = DisplayName
        _serviceName = ServiceName
        _serviceStatus = ServiceStatus
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _serviceStatus
    End Function
End Class
```

When i step through in debug mode it seems to being to populate the dictionary
display name: Application Experience
service name: AElookUpSVC
service status: Running (4)

When it tries to move onto the next item i get the following error:

> Null reference exception was unhandled:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can't for the life of me work out where it is finding a null reference?

Comment: In future, please just edit new information into your existing question, don't re-ask in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting your question makes it much harder for others to interpret the answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize your dictionary with `New`:

```
Dim dictservice As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Services)

Public Sub GetService()
    Dim localServices As ServiceController() = ServiceController.GetServices()
    For Each service As ServiceController In localServices
        dictservice.Add(service.DisplayName, New Services(service.DisplayName, service.ServiceName, service.Status.ToString))
    Next
End Sub
```

Right now it's `Nothing`, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem appears to be that `dictService` is `Nothing` and hence you get a `NullReferenceException`.  Where do you initialize / declare `dictService` and are you certain the initialization happens before this method?

If this is not the problem have you tried running this with the debugger attached?  it should point you to the line that is failing.